# How to create generic Java objects in ColdFusion

Tags: java, generics, coldfusion

I am trying to use Elasticsearch's Java API.

I am trying to create a [RestClientBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder.java).

```
Host=createObject("java", "org.apache.http.HttpHost").init(variables.HostName, variables.Port);
Node=createObject("java", "org.elasticsearch.client.Node").init(Host);
NodeList=createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList").init();
NodeList.add(Node);

RestClient=createObject("java", "org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder").init(NodeList).build();
```

I get the error

> Unable to find a constructor for class org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder that accepts parameters of type ( java.util.ArrayList ).

I assume it is because I need to create the ArrayList  as

```
java.util.ArrayList<org.elasticsearch.client.Node>
```

but this

```
NodeList=createObject("java", "java.util.ArrayList<org.elasticsearch.client.Node>").init()
```

does not work.

I am trying it this way, because using the [RestClient.builder()](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.java) method does not seem to work.  That might be because of some incompatibility with the varargs and ColdFusion?

Comment: Don't know the API, but that constructor doesn't look public, so the error may mean it's not accessible.  How did you try and use builder()? I remember seeing something about CF using arrays. Maybe try building a regular CF array and populate it with Node objects. Then javacast it to a java array.   `RestClient.builder( javacast("org.elasticsearch.client.Node[]", yourCFArrayVariable))`

Comment: ... fwiw, normally CF handles generics automatically. Assuming the constructor were public, you should've been able to pass in a CF array of Node objects (which is a java.util.List) and have it work out of the gate - AFAIK.

Comment: You'll need to elaborate on "RestClient.builder() method does not seem to work." and explain what your end goal is. Have you tried to get the api to work in a java app?

Comment: @Ageax you are correct the issue was that the constructor is not public.  The error that made me try this route I have posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52996435/error-in-coldfusion-javacast-array-to-class-from-loadpaths/52996436#52996436 along with a possible answer.  If you do have any input on that issue, please do =]

Comment: Scratch that. I was able to reproduce the other error. It was a case difference of all things .. weird.

Comment: As far as the issue on this thread, also try using a CF array (no javacast).  Didn't have time to build elasticsearch, but this POC worked for me: https://pastebin.com/iy2KPire