# Error in ColdFusion Javacast array to class from loadPaths

Tags: java, coldfusion

I am trying to use Elasticsearch's Java API.

I am trying to create a [RestClientBuilder](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/client/rest/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClientBuilder.java).

```
Host=createObject("java", "org.apache.http.HttpHost").init(variables.HostName, variables.Port);
Node=createObject("java", "org.elasticsearch.client.Node").init(Host);

RestClient=createObject("java", "org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient").builder(Javacast("org.elasticsearch.client.Node[]", [Node])).build();
```

I get the error

> Cannot convert the value to Java array because type org.elasticsearch.client.Node is unknown.

Also if I just try to use:

```
RestClient=createObject("java", "org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient").builder(Javacast("org.apache.http.HttpHost[]", [Host]));
```

I get the following error

> Either there are no methods with the specified method name and
>   argument types or the builder method is overloaded with argument types
>   that ColdFusion cannot decipher reliably. ColdFusion found 0 methods
>   that match the provided arguments. If this is a Java object and you
>   verified that the method exists, use the javacast function to reduce
>   ambiguity.

This I assume is because ColdFusion doesn't play nicely with varargs

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround using this method

https://www.bennadel.com/blog/1980-tojava---a-coldfusion-user-defined-function-for-complex-java-casting.htm

I believe there is a bug with Javacast and javaSettings loadPaths not being used.

> coldfusion.runtime.Cast$UnknownTypeException: Cannot convert the value
>   to Java array because type org.elasticsearch.client.Node is unknown.
>   at coldfusion.runtime.Cast.toJavaArray(Cast.java:1602)

Additionally if I try to perform the actiuons that the UDF takes

```
local.javaClass = createObject("java", "org.apache.http.HttpHost");
local.HostArrayReflect = createObject("java", "java.lang.reflect.Array");
local.HostArray = local.HostArrayReflect.newInstance(
    local.javaClass.GetClass()
    , JavaCast( "int", ArrayLen(local.Hosts))
);
for (i=0; i LT ArrayLen(local.Hosts); i=i+1) {
    local.HostArrayReflect.Set(local.HostArray, JavaCast("int", i), local.Hosts[i]);
}
```

I get the error

> An exception occurred while instantiating a Java object. The class
>   must not be an interface or an abstract class. If the class has a
>   constructor that accepts an argument, you must call the constructor
>   explicitly using the init(args) method. Error :
>   org.apache.http.HttpHost
>
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.http.HttpHost.() at
>   java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:412) at
>   coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.createObjectWithDefaultConstructor(JavaProxy.java:209)
>   at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:92)

This happens when I try to run `getClass()`, but in the UDF there is no issue.  A coworker tried to run this on Lucee and it seems to have worked, so I believe there is a bug in CF related to this.

Comment: *when I try to run getClass()*  Crazy as it sounds the error happens because the code uses `GetClass()` (notice the case) but not when using `getClass()` (camel case).  Haven't figured out why yet, but I'd guess maybe "getClass() is hard coded to return the class and everything else is handled like a [JavaBean getter/setter](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/using-java-objects.html).